# Magento2 : Move billing address after payment method

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, billing-address, onestepcheckout

How can I move Billing address after Payment method section?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has default settings. Go to:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> Checkout Options -> Display Billing Address On**

Select **Payment Page** and save configuration.

[image]
Clear cache.

Comment: Yes,it's working in demo but not in my website,is there any other dependancy?

Comment: I'm using amasty checkout that's why.can you help me with that?